# How to add a an additional point location while plotting geopandas dataframe using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am using the following code to plot an additional coordinate/point on top of a matplotlib plot of a geopandas dataframe. However, as the image indicates the point is not overlapping the choropleth - it should, since the latitude & longitude lies within the geographic location for which the data has been obtained from census. Please advise.

```
from cenpy import products
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
%matplotlib inline

tustin = products.ACS(2018).from_county('Orange County, CA', level='tract',
                                        variables=['B23025_005E', 'B23025_003E'])
tustin['pct_unemployed'] = tustin.B23025_005E / tustin.B23025_003E * 100
print(tustin.crs)

# additional data co-ordinate
lat = 3374569.5
lon = -11782886.0
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Place': ['X'],
     'Latitude': [lat],
     'Longitude': [lon]})

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

# setting the same crs as the main geopandas dataframe
gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}

# plot the first dataframe 'tustin' as a choropleth
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,20))
tustin.dropna(subset=['pct_unemployed'], axis=0).plot('pct_unemployed', ax=ax, cmap='plasma')
ax.set_facecolor('k')
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
#ax.plot(-13144890.450, 3992372.350, "ro")
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEoI8.png)

Comment: Are you sure the point should overlap? (how did you obtain those coordinates?) Can you show the output of `tustin.total_bounds`? (that can tell the total bounds of the coordinates of the dataframe, to check if the point actually overlaps with that)

Comment: Thanks much @joris. Here is what I see as total_bounds: array([-13149715.04,   3939720.19, -13070353.93,   4021772.99]). You are right. 
Even though I know the point is geographically (address) within the county represented by the cenpy result, I think I am missing some conversion. Any ideas on how to convert a pair of la/lon (CENTLAT': '+33.7456950', 'CENTLON': '-117.8288600') to the coordinate system returned from census. I was using a very naive (and misinformed) approach.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out a way using pypoj. Although I have to understand this in more detail.
proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857, always_xy=True)

x1, y1 = (float(lon), float(lat))
x2, y2 = proj.transform(x1, y1)
print((x2, y2))